# procedure to delete data from table when data in a row exceeds than 30 thousand in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure to delete data from table when data in a row exceeds than 30 thousand and before deleting the data it will create a backup of database and then it will delete the data.Any help will be greatly  appreciated.

Comment: You can use trigger for that

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some example data, and expected output? Showing some effort encourages others to answer. Keep in mind, that SO is not a code generator service, please help us to be able to help you. I'd like to recommend to read [ask] in [help].

Comment: can u please help me suppose that there is a table called notificationtemp and i want to delete records when it exceeds over 30 thousand rows and before deleting records it will create backup of my database called recharge.

Comment: Keywords to search for: `HAVING`, `DELETE .. OUTPUT INTO`, `ROW_NUMBER()`, `Common Table Expression`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below trigger it may help you.

Below trigger will delete the top 1000 old records in your table whenever
the row count exceeds 30000 (Change the delete count in trigger as per your need)

```
create trigger Records_delete on Test_table

after insert
as begin

declare @count bigint

select @count= COUNT(*) from Test_table 

--select @count

IF @count>30000
BEGIN


;WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT TOP (1000) *  FROM Test_table ORDER BY Test_table_nbr 
 )
 DELETE FROM CTE

END

end
```

**Note:** Your table count never exceeds more than 30000 after creating this trigger on your table

Answer (score 1):

You need [Partitioned Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx)

Also check this [Partitioned Table and Index Strategies Using SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd578580(sql.100).aspx)